# How to manage server pool in memcached?

Tags: php, memcached

Let's assume I use memcached with a named pool with some servers added. It could look like that:

```
<?php
$mc = new Memcached('mc');
$mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE, true);
if (!count($mc->getServerList())) {
    $mc->addServers(array(
        array('mc1.example.com',11211),
        array('mc2.example.com',11211),
    ));
}
?>
```

Now, let's assume I want to rearrange the servers. I know I can add servers to the named pool by simply executing addServer(s) method. But can I remove servers? Or simply replace the whole list?

Comment: you mean commenting them out doesn't work?

Comment: If I name a pool, the server list is persistent. If I connect again to a pool with the same name with: $mc = new Memcached('mc') the server list is already there.